# The recognizer has not been initialized, make sure to call Recognizer.getInstance().initialize() first

Tags: android, microblink

Caused by: com.microblink.RecognizerNotInitializedException: The recognizer has not been initialized, make sure to call Recognizer.getInstance().initialize() first.

I think the sdk is not able to release camera instance after use, so next time when capture receipt is invoked again after going back I am getting this issue.

I can see this log repeating in logcat even when the activity is closed

```
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now  CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
```

You can reproduce it on your sample sdk as well just use the custom recognizer view.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this error add this:

```
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
    if (_controller == null || !_controller!.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      _controller?.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (_controller != null) {
        print('muere');
      }
    }
  }
```

its called in initState

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.detached);
  }
```

The documentation tells us about this:

> Handling Lifecycle states # As of version 0.5.0 of the camera plugin,
> lifecycle changes are no longer handled by the plugin. This means
> developers are now responsible to control camera resources when the
> lifecycle state is updated. Failure to do so might lead to unexpected
> behavior (for example as described in issue #39109). Handling
> lifecycle changes can be done by overriding the
> didChangeAppLifecycleState method like so: